# Search child node in XML by sub-node content

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm a noob whith XPath and I have a question: How can I search for a child in all branches by a particular name and display the information in the XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movie><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movie>
  <film>
    <name>Peaceful Warrior</name>
    <actor>Scott Mechlowicz</actor>
  </film>
  <film>
    <name>Gone</name>
    <actor>Scott Mechlowicz</actor>
  </film>
  <film>
    <name>Gladiator</name>
    <actor>Russel Crowe</actor>
  </film> 
</movie>
```

I tried:

```xml
//*[ancestor::movie/film[name = "Scott Mechlowicz"]]
```

But this shows all the information, when my intention is to show only movies in which that actor participates.

Is this possible with XPath or must I use `getNameByTagName` `NodeList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath. If you are just trying to get a list of names of movies, try this XPath (get name of film where actor = "Scott Mechlowicz")

```
//film[actor = "Scott Mechlowicz"]/name
```

or

```
/movie/film[actor = "Scott Mechlowicz"]/name
```